# How to insert primary keyless entity to table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm working on with 15 years old DB.Now our scenario is DB first ,inserting an entity to primary keyless table.I read a lots of microsoft EF Core docs such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations. And they said not supported as a conclusion .

Firstly,I added HasNokey() as a usual then it gave an exception. After that, I added dummy primary key in entity class then HasKey(x=>x.DummyId) Ignore(x=>x.DummyId) it.But it didn't work again.Now I'm confused.

How to handle this problem guys? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can you add a class of the entity, the related config, and the SQL DDL of the table? On first try I think to stored proc to insert/edit/delete the entity and config as a view for reading.

Comment: HasNoKey seems okay, I think there is another problem. Could you give more detail or show your code?

Comment: First of all,Thanks for all reply guys.I worked on it almost a day then after I met my senior.We decided to create view which is included this table and manipulate table by stored procedure.However after, we understood that no need extra effort like that and we chose easiest way by adding two columns as a unique key.       
As a conclusion,Ef core does not support manipulation on primary keyless tables so it leads to create your unique keys and that's the easiest way to handle this issue . @Max

Answer (score 3):

EF Core does not directly support updating, deleting, and inserting into keyless tables with a `DbSet` as of version 5.0.

There are two solutions I am aware of

**Raw SQL Query**

In EF Core, it is possible to execute raw SQL Commands. You could create a SQL command to perform the insert and execute it manually. Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) does not cover your exact use case, but you can use raw or interpolated SQL Directly on the `Database` member of a `DbContext`.

```cs
    var ctx = new DbContext(options);
    ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("INSERT INTO Table_Name .....");
```

**Change Database Schema**
You could add an primary key column to the schema such that EF core would be able to use it as intended for updates, inserts, and deletes. Broadly speaking, the change would follow the steps as below.

1. Create a new table identical to the old table
2. Add an auto-incremented, primary key column
3. Copy the data from old table to new table
4. Delete old table
5. Rename new table to name of old table

Once complete, you would need to change your entity definitions as shown below.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ConfigTemplate>(entity =>
    {
         // Adding the key itself, using the index name as well
         entity.HasKey(e => e.primary_key)
               .HasName("PRIMARY");

         // Adding the index definition is not a required
         entity.HasIndex(e => e.primary_key)
               .HasName("PRIMARY");

         entity.ToTable("config_template");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its impossible to delete table and also thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

if your keyless table got some other columns which could be used as composite keys, you can try to update config for that entity in dbcontext as a workaround, but I agree with that modify exist table with a new primary key is a better solution

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SampleEntity>(entity =>
 {
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Property1, e.Property2  });
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can think about add dummy primary key for each entity.