# Entity Framework Core database-first approach: how to save record into database with a table without primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using a database-first approach to insert data into my SQL Server database. My table has no primary key. Here is the data model class:

```
[Keyless]
public class Attendance
{
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int GateId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the method to insert record into database.

```
public bool AddAttendance(Attendance Attendance)
{
    try
    {
        _dbContext.Attendances.Add(Attendance);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw;
        return false;
    }
}
```

On the `_dbContext.Attendances.Add(Attendance);` statement, I get the following error:

> Unable to track an instance of type 'Attendance' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with a primary key may be tracked.

I cannot modify table to assign key, as this database is being used by different applications.

Please guide me, how can I resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: add an identidy field

Comment: this answer provides many alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68935591/how-to-insert-primary-keyless-entity-to-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CarlVerret provided the good link with two solutions: use raw SQL and define a primary key in the db context definition. In the last solution ensure that the defined key is unique, and you don't need to/will not modify it.

You may create a primary key for the table within the database, generally it should not affect most applications.